# Rails : Access other object in a one-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So here's my code :

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :neededingredients
end
```

```
class Neededingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :ingredients
    belongs_to :recipes
end
```

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :neededingredients
end
```

And here's my migration :

```
create_table :recipes do |recipes|
    recipes.string :name, null: false
    recipes.string :indications, null: false
end

create_table :ingredients do |ingredients|
    ingredients.string :ingredient, null: false, uniqueness: true
end

create_table :neededingredients do |neededingredients|
    neededingredients.integer :quantity, null: false
    neededingredients.string :unit
    neededingredients.references :ingredients, foreign_key: true
    neededingredients.references :recipes, foreign_key: true
end
```

So a Recipe has multiple NeededIngredients. A NeededIngredient has a reference to an Ingredient, and has a quantity and a unit (grams, for example). I'd like to be able to do something like `a_recipe.neededingredients` to find all neededingredients of a given recipe, or `a_needed_ingredient.recipe`to get the recipe of a given neededingredient. For some reason, I can't find a way to do this. Is there anything wrong in my migration or in my model ? Thanks for the help !

Comment: did you tried `has_many :through` association https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 2):

The key of the issue here is really bad naming / pluralization. I would highly really recommend that you rename this according to [the Ruby conventions](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#naming-conventions) to avoid confusion and future bugs.

Class names should be CamelCase - `NeededIngredient`. Do seperate compound words!

Attributes, table names, instance variables, routes, method names and everything else should be snake_case - `needed_ingredient` or `needed_ingredients` depending on the context.

This is much easier to read and get right then `insanelylongthingwitteninlowercase`.

Cramming three different table definitions into a single migration (if that is what you're doing) is a bad idea. Especially since its trivial to generate migrations though the model generator. Having separate migrations lets you run them sequentially and roll them back individually to get it right.

```
class CreateNeededIngredients < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    # there is no need to use super long block argument names
    create_table :needed_ingredients do |t|
      t.decimal :quantity, null: false # yeah decimal
      t.string :unit
      t.references :ingredient, foreign_key: true # this should be singular!
      t.references :recipe, foreign_key: true # this should be singular!
      t.timestamps
    end
    # consider adding a unique index to avoid duplicates
    # add_index: :needed_ingredients, [:ingredient_id, :recipe_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Not that the argument to `references` should be singular since its the name of the foreign key. Rails will deduce the target table by inflection.

You then need to setup a [`has_many through:` association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) to tie recipe and ingredients together:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :needed_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :needed_ingredients
end

class NeededIngredient
  belongs_to :recipe # belongs_to is always singular!
  belongs_to :ingredient # belongs_to is always singular!
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :needed_ingredients
  has_many :recipies, through: :needed_ingredients
end
```

And this is not a one-to-many assocation. Its many-to-many. If you need to display the ingredients of recipe you should note that you should loop through the needed_ingredients association and not ingredients.

```
class NeededIngredient
  belongs_to :recipe # belongs_to is always singular!
  belongs_to :ingredient # belongs_to is always singular!

  # use delegation/proxing to avoid Law of Demeter violations
  def name
    ingredient.ingredient # why isn't this column just called name?
  end
end
```

```
class RecipiesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.include(:ingedients).find(params[:id])
  end 
end
```

```
# app/views/recipies/show.html.erb
<h1><%= @recipe.name %></h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @recipe.needed_ingredients.each do |i|%>
    <tr>
      <td><%= i.name %></td>
      <td><%= i.quantity %> <%= i.unit %></td>  
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use plural instead of singular (in the migration, and in the model), and you should use [has_many :through association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Change the following:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :neededingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :neededingredients
end

class Neededingredient < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :ingredient
    belongs_to :recipe
end

class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :neededingredients
    has_many :recipes, through: :neededingredients
end

create_table :neededingredients do |neededingredients|
    neededingredients.integer :quantity, null: false
    neededingredients.string :unit
    neededingredients.references :ingredient, foreign_key: true
    neededingredients.references :recipe, foreign_key: true
end
```

Now you can call (for example): `Recipe.first.ingredients`, `Recipe.first.neededingredients`, `Ingredient.first.recipes`